# HTTPS on Elastic Beanstalk (EB) default address / URL (without custom domain name)

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, heroku, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have my back-end for a mobile app hosted on Elastic Beanstalk on the default address (e.g. xxxxx.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com). I would like to use HTTPS for this address.

I've followed the instructions on the following 3 links to create and self-sign a certificate and add it to the Load Balancer on my EB app. However, I get a warning ("Your connection is not private") when visiting the address in my browser (not a problem in theory as it's just hosting a back-end), and also get errors making API requests to the https address.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-ssl.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-ssl-upload.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html

What can I do, besides setting up a custom domain? I know Heroku offer https straight away for apps hosted on their service, does AWS offer something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using https, you need to make sure the domain of the URL of your server is equal to the URL of the certificate. Otherwise, you will see the mentioned warning on browsers and your API requests won`t work.

There are some websites where you can create a free SSL certificate mapping to the domain of your Elastic Beanstalk application. I recommend this [one](https://www.sslforfree.com/).

Comment: sslforfree looks great, thanks. the certificates expire after 90 days which I can work with for now, though if you know anything with longer that would be great too.

Comment: sslforfree doesn't seem to allow that anymore, unless I'm doing it wrong. How did you pass the domain ownership verification step?

Comment: Yes, it is still working. I've just renewed my certificates this week. To pass the domain verification, select the Manual Verification, then download the verification file, and paste it on a folder called 'public/.well-known/acme-challenge' inside your application.

Comment: Is it really possible? You would have to get a certificate for `*.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com` which is not yours domain.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a ssl certificate. The AWS certificate manager won't work and a self-signed certificate won't work either [unless your goal is to secure the connection between the load balancer and the EC2 instance in which case a self-signed works]. I personally like using sslforfree.com. Most similar sites offer a free 90-day certificate.

The real question is: How do you verify the ownership of the beanstalk domain? This is how you do it:

- choose a site that allows you to verify using a file which is publicly served by your server. The DNS or Email methods won't work.
- set up your server to serve static assets and serve the downloaded file. The file usually will be served under a directory similar to the following: "/.well-known/pki-validation/THE_AUTH_FILE_HERE". In other words, you should go to: YOUR_BEANSTALK_DOMAIN.com/.well-known/pki-validation/THE_AUTH_FILE in a browsers and be abled to read the file's contents.
- You should be able to download the certificate.
- go to the AWS certificate manager and import the certificate. You'll have to open the contents of the public certificate, private key, and certificate chain/bundle using some text editor [my IDE opens them just fine] and copy paste them into the certificate manager.
- add a load balancer in the configuration of your elastic beanstalk environment. In the "Load Balancer" section of configuration, add https listener to port 443, map it to http instance listening on port 80, add the ssl certificate from the dropdown list [this is the one we just added in the certificate manager].

Comment: Upvote for the step by step explanation. Manual verification by serving file via URL is the method to be used to verify the elasticbeanstalk.com subdomain.